# Create a recursive join graph on neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a table with two fields: product and parent product.
The data is similar to this

```
Prod  Parent  
  A      A1  
 A1      B1  
  B      A1  
 B1       C
```

How to create a graph where I tie in the product to its parent so that I can query all levels? E.g if I query on A, I need to know about its parent A1, grandparent B1 and one level higher C. I need to be able to traverse any which way, but how do I create the node and relationship to do recursive looks.

Comment: Have a look at: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html

Answer (score 1):

**The Datamodel**

Given your description and the sample data, your graph looks something like this:

[image: property graph model]

**Creating the graph**

Given a CSV file with the contents:

```
"Prod","Parent"
"A","A1"
"A1","B1"
"B","A1"
"B1","C"
```

You can create this graph in Neo4j using [`LOAD CSV`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) Cypher statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/file.csv' AS row
MERGE (prod:Product {name: row.Prod})
MERGE (parent:Product {name: row.Parent)
CREATE UNIQUE (parent)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->(prod)
```

**Querying the graph**

Find the parents of product A1:

```
MATCH (p:Product {name: "A1"})<-[:IS_PARENT_OF]-(parent:Product)
RETURN parent
```

Find all ancestors (arbitrary depth) of A1:

```
MATCH (p:Product {name: "A1"})<-[:IS_PARENT_OF*1..15]-(a:Product)
RETURN a
```